# How to use Adblock AND a VPN on my Android Phone?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, android, privacy

I'm using Private Internet Access's VPN via its [App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.privateinternetaccess.android) and now I'd also like to additionally use [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/en/android-install).
The problem however is that I apparently can only use either VPN or Adblock Plus - but not both in combination.
Is it possible to use both by changing some setting in either of the Apps or of my phone ?

It says it couldn't change the proxy settings of my phone so I should do it manually. But as all traffic is routed through the VPN changing the proxy-name to "localhost" and the proxy-port to "2020" didn't help. It keeps on waiting for traffic on Port 2020. I guess it comes down to routing the VPN traffic through the proxy. But maybe there's also another solution to it (like another Adblock App that works differently for example).

---

**My phone**:
Samsung Galaxy Ace 2, I8160
Firmware 4.1.2
Rooted

**The Error Message** (roughly translated):
"Seemingly no traffic was routed through adblock plus. Adblock plus couldn't change the proxy settings of your device. Please configure them manually."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well the issue has been [resolved by now](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86481/how-to-use-adblock-and-a-vpn). As I have a rooted phone I was able to use **[AdAway](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.adaway)** which doesn't need a proxy to be set up.

Comment: Note that there are also other Adblockers than the one I mentioned. Also alternatively users without root can use the **Firefox browser with an Adblock (e.g. Adblock Plus) AddOn**.